# PL/SQL select into - if data exists

Tags: plsql

I need to select into a local variable only if there exists data.

```
SELECT column1 INTO local_variable FROM table1 where column2 = <condition>;
```

Here if there is no data matching the condition I get a no data found error.

I need to select into the local variable only if there is some data matching the condition. Is there a simple query that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably the best way is to handle no_data_found

```
begin
  SELECT column1 INTO local_variable 
  FROM table1 where column2 = p_val;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    local_variable := null;
end;
```

Also, if you are selecting with primary key /unique key (that is column2 is unique) then there is a trick you can do

```
SELECT max(column1) INTO local_variable 
  FROM table1 where column2 = p_val;
```

Comment: Why is max() necessary?

Comment: You will not get no_data_found when you select max(), you will just get null value when there exists no such row `where column2 = p_val`. So this is just a trick that can be used to defend against no_data_found exception, although I believe it is better to handle this exception explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Well…do a count before doing the select. Or just handle the no_data_found exception.

You can open a cursor and fetch the rows, do a count and if it is greater than 0 then do your stuff with that record