# Error ORA-06550 & ORA-00933

Tags: plsql

I'm getting the following errors:

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 43:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

.

```
declare minimum number (10);
begin
SELECT MIN(SWLR_ASSET_ID) from SWLR_ASSET INTO minnumber where swlr_key=:p26_swlr_id;        
end;
```

I believe its a simple syntax error somewhere, but as far as I know everything seems good. When I take out the into and just run the select statement by itself then it works.

Comment: I figured out the solution, I needed brackets on MIN(SWLR_ASSET_ID).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PL/SQL select into - if data exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316315/pl-sql-select-into-if-data-exists)

Comment: @jWeaver, this has nothing to do with a No Data Found error.

Comment: mistakenly selected other.. it was possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle

Comment: That's also different.  That's about creating a new table based on a SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `INTO` in the wrong place, and you also declared a variable named `minimum` but then selected into `minnumber`.  The correct code would be:

```
declare minimum number (10);
begin
  SELECT MIN(SWLR_ASSET_ID)
  INTO minimum 
  from SWLR_ASSET 
  where swlr_key=:p26_swlr_id;        
end;
```